# Custom Woocommerce product weight calculation from dimensions only for specific shipping methods

Tags: php, woocommerce, dimension, shipping-method

I am trying to set up a dimensional weight counting method when the dimensional weight (width x height x length) of the product is greater than the weight (actual weight).

I found [Custom Woocommerce product weight calculation from dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46768483/custom-woocommerce-product-weight-calculation-from-dimensions/46769325#46769325) answer code that works perfectly.

However I would like to make it works only for specific shipping method(s).
Any advice or help?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_weight', 'custom_get_weight_from_dimensions', 10, 2 );
function custom_get_weight_from_dimensions( $weight, $product ) {
    $chosen_shipping  = WC()->session->get('chosen_shipping_methods')[0]; 

    // How to restrict to specific shipping methods?

    $dim_weight = $product->get_length() * $product->get_width() * $product->get_height() / 5000;
    return $dim_weight > $weight ? $dim_weight : $weight;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following targeting specific shipping methods only *(see at the end, how to get your shipping method rate ids)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_weight', 'custom_get_weight_from_dimensions', 10, 2 );
function custom_get_weight_from_dimensions( $weight, $product ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        // Here set your targeted shipping method rate Ids
        $targetted_shipping_ids  = array( 'flat_rate:12', 'flat_rate:14' );
        
        // Get chosen shipping method(s)
        $chosen_shipping_methods  = (array) WC()->session->get('chosen_shipping_methods'); 
        $matched_shipping_methods = array_intersect( $chosen_shipping_methods, $targetted_shipping_ids );
        
        if( ! empty($matched_shipping_methods) ) {
            $dim_weight = $product->get_length() * $product->get_width() * $product->get_height() / 5000;
        }
    }

    return isset($dim_weight) && $dim_weight > $weight ? $dim_weight : $weight;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**How to get the shipping method rate ID:**

> To get the related **shipping methods rate IDs**, something like **`flat_rate:12`**, inspect with your browser code inspector each related radio button attribute **`value`** like:
>
> [image]

Comment: thank you very much for your help:) I have changed array_instersect to array_intersect and works perfectly.

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec, I found that this code only works on single product, do you have any idea for variable products?